# numpy array performance versus standard python lists/arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on some matrix manipulation code that will be running on a raspberry pi (it's generating animations for an LED matrix). I keep seeing references to numpy being much faster at array/matrix operations but haven't quite been able to grok what the difference is. My arrays are just standard:

```
[[123],[456],[789]] #only MUCH bigger
```

Is it worth even looking into numpy?

Comment: The difference can be huge if your arrays are large, but it depends what operations you're doing on them.

Comment: Numpy is more efficient because it is designed for mathematical and scientific computations in mind.